# How to pass an optional value to objective c class from swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, option-type

Below is my code

```
var img = self.appDelegate.loadImageFromCache(imageURL)!
if (img != nil) {
    cell.imageArray.append(img!)
}
```

Even if the img object is available I'm getting error as

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

My cell class is an objective c class and the imageArray is a property.

Comment: Maybe cell or cell.imageArray are nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. First you force to unwrap optional value (line 1) and then checking if it is nil. If it is nil then it blows up in line 1. If it isn't then you don't need to check it in line 2. Here is the correct way to write this:

```
if let image = self.appDelegate.loadImageFromCache(imageURL) {
    cell.imageArray.append(image)
}
```

The if let statement tries to unwrap the result of the expression and if it can it assigns the result to image. Then executes the code inside if let. If it can't it omits the if let statment.

Edit: you have to check everything comes from objective-c. So rewriting it

```
if let image = self.appDelegate.loadImageFromCache(imageURL) {
        cell.imageArray?.append(image)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you the second solution work. I've tried the first solution and that too failed that's you posted here. Thank you again.

Comment: Even it works now that doesn't mean all is well. Probably you have a bug in your code now. The imageArray is nil and nothing is stored inside it.